# Write polynomial inequality from given graph

Tags: inequality, polynomials, roots

[image]

From the above graph I want to write `polynomial inequality`.

From the graph, I derived that it has 3 roots. And Polynomial equation can be something like `(x+2)(x-1)(x-4)`.

I can also say that for root `-2`, it can be something like `x <= -2` and for second line it'll be `1 < x < 4`.

But I'm stuck when I combine all 3 roots. I'm not sure will it be `< 0` or `> 0`? And how do I conclude that?

For the same graph, I can write range as `{ x | x <= -2 and 1 < x < 4}`. Does it matter if I put `or` in place of `and` or it is same thing? In computer programming languages, it has totally different meaning for `and` and `or`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that if you use the graph of the function
$$f(x)=(x+2)(x-1)(x-4)$$
And treat the number line as the x-axis, then the black ray from $-2$ to $-\infty$ is always above it. Furthermore, the excluded portion from $-2$ to $1$ is always below an arch in the graph, after which it dips below from $1$ to $4$, then goes up to $+\infty$.

[image]

Notice that all of the included parts on the number line (except maybe at the zeroes) are above the graph and the excluded parts are below. Thus we may use the inequality
$$(x+2)(x-1)(x-4)\lt 0$$
which works for your plot, except for a discrepancy at $x=-2$.

If you want to write this using set builder notation, you could use
$$\{x|x \le 2\}\cup\{x|1\lt x\lt4\}$$

Does this work for you?

Comment: `discrepancy at x=−2x=−2.`. You mean to say that it should not have been filled circle, just open like other circles.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: If I want to summarize, if graph stays below x-axis for all the shaded parts, than I can put `< 0 ` or I have to put ` > 0`

Comment: As I specified in my answer, you should use $(x+2)(x-1)(x-4) \lt 0$.